# How to link main.c with CUnit library in terminal?

Tags: c, tdd, cunit

I am working with CUnit and learning test driven development.

Please can someone help me out with the compilation part.

my command in terminal is:

gcc -main.c -o main

this is obviously not correct as i get the following output :

FOR EVERY FUNCTION

main.c:(.text+0x1ee): undefined reference to `CU_initialize_registry'
main.c:(.text+0x1f7): undefined reference to`CU_get_error'
main.c:(.text+0x210): undefined reference to `CU_add_suite'
main.c:(.text+0x22a): undefined reference to`CU_add_test'
main.c:(.text+0x240): undefined reference to `CU_add_test'
main.c:(.text+0x256): undefined reference to`CU_add_test'
main.c:(.text+0x260): undefined reference to `CU_set_output_filename'
main.c:(.text+0x265): undefined reference to`CU_automated_run_tests'
main.c:(.text+0x26a): undefined reference to `CU_cleanup_registry'
main.c:(.text+0x26f): undefined reference to`CU_get_error'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

I need to know how to link the libcunit.a with the gcc .

I have tried gcc -o main  main.c -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-Bstatic -lcunit -Wl,-Bdynamic

It does comile and when i run ./main it sort of uses 100% cpu (continously) and there  are no results !!!!
I have to exit the process using ctrl + c .

Comment: If it runs endlessly, you will need to show your code. The problem is some logical error in your code.

Comment: so is the compiling command correct ??

Comment: If it is compiled and linked successfully the command must be correct, unless you link to wrong version of library which again is a logical error.

Comment: ok... thanks !! i dont have permission to post the code . other wise you could have helped me much more...:)

Comment: hey...i found why the code ran endlessly...the function was doing a large computation ! so i reduced the value to a manageble level and it worked !!